# First two pages are empty. There is a bug in cls

Tags: documentclass-writing

there are two empty page before title.I think there is a bug in cls file. 
thanks

online :
https://cloud.sagemath.com/projects/28237dba-3851-4c63-8de3-fb49e5ecd8c0/files/template/

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX. Rather than giving links please add a [minimal working example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/) that takes the form `\documentclass{...}\usepackage{....}\begin{document}...\end{document}`. If possible, it should compile and have the minimum amount of code needed to illustrate your problem. This makes it much easier for people to help you - and much more likely that they will!

Comment: My impression is that the class is buggy. If I remove the `\onecolumn` call at the end of it, your example ends up being one page only, but the example template has *two* blank pages at the beginning instead of just one. Since there doesn't appear the class provides for two column output, all the parts where it switches from two column to one column are of very dubious usefulness.

Comment: @egreg the problem is in line 88 file `metu12.def` and `metu11.def` `\newcommand\@chapapp{CHAPTER}\vspace*{\fill}` so you need to delete or uncomment `\vspace*{\fill}`. more than what egreg said the class is very non standard

Comment: @touhami Really! Make it an answer, please.

Comment: Can you please inform the maintainer of the template about this thread?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

the problem is in line 88 file `metu12.def` and `metu11.def`

```
\newcommand\@chapapp{CHAPTER}\vspace*{\fill}
```

so you need to delete or uncomment `\vspace*{\fill}`.

Comment: @touhami: Asking for upvoting your answer? ;-)